# For Objective-C ... Pointer to method

Tags: objective-c, pointers, methods, dispatch

I want to setup a Method dispatch table and I am wondering if it is possible to create pointer to a method in Objective-C (like pointer to function in C).  I tried to use some Objective-C runtime functions to dynamically switch methods but the problem is it will affect all instances.

As I am very new to Objective-C, an illustrated example would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Objective-C methods are called `selector`s, and are represented by the `SEL` datatype. If your object inherits from `NSObject`, you can tell it to perform a selector (i.e. call a method) like thus:

```
SEL selector = @selector(doSomething:);
[obj performSelector:selector withObject:argument];
```

This assumes you have a method defined such as:

```
-(void)doSomething:(MyObject*)arg;
```

Selectors are assigned to `SEL` datatypes through the `@selector` keyword, which takes the name of the method you would like to keep. The name of the method is the method name stripped of all arguments. For example:

```
-(void)doSomething:(MyObject*)arg withParams:(MyParams*)params
```

Would be referenced as `@selector(doSomething:withParams:)`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes! In Objective-C, function pointers are called selectors. If you have a method defined like this:

```
- (void)myFunctionWithObject:(NSObject*)obj otherObject:(NSNumber*)obj2
{
}
```

The selector is declared like this:

```
@selector(myFunctionWithObject:otherObject:)
```

To perform a selector on an object, you can use:

```
[object performSelector:@selector(myFunction)];
```

or

```
[object performSelector:@selector(myFunctionTakingParameter:) withObject: o];
```

The selector data type is particularly useful for threads and timers, where you can dispatch a thread and provide it a selector to the message you'd like it to invoke. If you need to create an array of selectors (or a dispatch table), or if you need to invoke selectors with multiple parameters, you can use the NSInvocation class. It provides a wrapper for a selector and allows you to specify actual arguments.

You should keep in mind that Objective-C is already based on a fully dynamic method dispatch table. It sounds like maintaining function pointers using selectors will work fine for you if you just need a reference to a function, though.

Comment: You might want to change the second sentence to read: If you have a METHOD defined like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ben.  Yes, you are absolutely right that the runtime is itself a fully dynamic patch table.